# WCF/IIS application - Multiple HTTPS Site Bindings breaks application

Tags: wcf, iis

I am having an issue with an application that we did not design. I'm not a dev, and the vendor is anything but helpful.

When launching the site and clicking a dropdown box that should display a list, this event gets logged on the IIS Server:

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>  Sender Information:System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/23324256
>  Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/API/JsonFetcher.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The ServiceHostBase object returned from the CreateServiceHost method of type 'SpectrumHR.API.JsonFetcher' is null.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The ServiceHostBase object returned from the CreateServiceHost method of type 'SpectrumHR.API.JsonFetcher' is null.
>    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>  Process Name: w3wp
>  Process ID: 4136

The site has two bindings in IIS:
https://name.com:443,
https://name.com:8443

When I remove one of the bindings, doesn't matter which one, the error disappears and the application works. In searching, I found this command that references this behavior:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

I added that to the web.config, but the error remains. Here is the stack trace when I browse to the jsonfetcher.svc

> [InvalidOperationException: The ServiceHostBase object returned from the CreateServiceHost method of type 'SpectrumHR.API.JsonFetcher' is null.]
>    System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +208409
>    System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +76
>    System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +901
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/API/JsonFetcher.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The ServiceHostBase object returned from the CreateServiceHost method of type 'SpectrumHR.API.JsonFetcher' is null..]
>    System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +624474
>    System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +196075
>    System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +101
>    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +913
>    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

Comment: What happens if you browse the .svc file?

Comment: @taleeb I get the same error when browsing to the .svc. Stack trace posted above.